# Excel - INDEX MATCH MATCH with a twist

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to assist some local firefighters make a crewing display page on their excel roster.  Their roster is setup with dates from 1st January -> 31st December vertically in column A with the names of each firefighter across the top in Row 1.  They then fill out which role any given person is working within the matrix.

On the display page they will have a section for each fire truck and want to display who is the driver for Truck 1, who is the pump operator for Truck 2 etc etc.

Now I'm familiar with using `INDEX MATCH MATCH` for finding a row and column and then return the intersecting value.  However in this case I need to find the date (vertically) then find the role on the same row as the found date (e.g. "Truck 1 Driver") and then return the column header (Name of firefighter performing that role on that day)

I'm very capable with VBA but I would like to avoid using it if I can achieve the same result with a forumla.  Unfortunately my formulas skills are lacking as I usually just use VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an INDEX/MATCH to return the correct row to the MATCH which will return the correct column to another INDEX:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MATCH(G$1,INDEX($B:$D,MATCH($F2,$A:$A,0),0),0))
```

[image]

Comment: So `G$1` being the date lookup and `$F2` being the shift name lookup?

Comment: no the other way around.  see the picture.  F2 is the date and G1 is the shift name lookup.

Comment: Sorry I'm on a rather locked down IT system currently and cant view imgr links

Comment: Works like a charm.  I had to create a few named ranges due to bouncing between two sheets, the formula was getting a bit long for excel's liking. Thanks!